# Differential equations and surjectivity of some linear operators

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $a_0,a_1,...a_{n-1}$ be some continuous functions $[0,1]\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Consider a linear operator $D:C^n[0,1]\longrightarrow C[0,1]$ which maps each $y\in C^n[0,1]$ to $y^{(n)}+a_{n-1}y^{(n-1)}+...+a_1y'+a_0y$. How to prove that $D$ is surjective? That is for all $f\in C[0,1]$ there is $y\in C^n[0,1]$ such that $f=D(y)$. I understand it is a kind of reformulation of some theorem from differential equations. Could you give me a link or explain how to prove that?

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to show that the $n-$th order ODE
$$
y^{(n)}+a_{n-1}y^{(n-1)}+\cdots+a_1y'+a_0y=f,\tag{1}
$$
has a solution for every $f\in C[0,1]$.

This is indeed true,vnad it is a standard result in the theory of linear ODEs.

In fact, a solution of $(1)$ can be obtained by the [variation of parameters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters) method.